# discord.js event voiceStateUpdate

Tags: node.js, discord.js

how can i get the time when the user joins the channel or leaves the channel 
`console.log(newMember.joinedTimestrap)` it gives me some numbers not the date and time (ex 1572014868278)
`console.log(newMember.joinedAt)` gives undefined

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = async (client,oldMember,newMember) => {
     if(newMember.bot) return;

     let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
     let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


     if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {



     } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){

       // User leaves a voice channel

     }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property in the GuildMember class for when a user joins the vc, the .joinedTimestrap is the timestamp for when that user joined the guild.

Now, to answer why it gave you some numbers and not the date, It's the date that he joined as a unix timestamp, to convert that in to a readable date, do the following:

```
let date = new Date(newMember.joinedTimestrap)

// Then you can use the Date class methods for getting the date, hour, minutes etc...
console.log(date)
```

The full list of methods available with the Date class can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Now, if you wanted to get the time that a user has joined a channel, just create a new Date object as soon as the event is triggered, and then log that:

```
let date = new Date()
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property `member.joinedTimestrap`, but assuming you meant `member.joinedTimestamp`, it is given in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can convert it to a conventional Date object by passing it to the Date constructor, i.e. `new Date(member.joinedTimestamp)` - this is what `member.joinedAt` does internally, so it should be a shortcut to give you the same answer.

However, that aside, `joinedAt` and `joinedTimestamp` are when the user joined the *server*, not the voiceChannel. The code is being run right as the user joins the voiceChannel, so you can just get the current time for that: `new Date()`

Comment: my bad typing mistake on Timestamp